# Add a sheet as an attachment not the whole workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I want the database sheet to be emailed as an attachment not the whole workbook.

```vb
Private Sub cmdEmail_Click()
    'Declare Outlook Variables
    Dim OLApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OLMail As Object
    'Open the Outlook Application and Start a new mail
    Set OLApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set OLMail = OLApp.CreateItem(0)
    OLApp.Session.Logon
    With OLMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = ""
        .body = ""
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Database")
        .Display
        ' .Send
    End With
    
    'Clearing Memory
    
    Set OLMail = Nothing
    Set OLApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Error is saying I cannot save this workbook name to choose another name or choose another workbook
[image]

Comment: Export the sheet to a new workbook and Attach this or export it as pdf or ... a worksheet is not an object to be an attachement

Comment: So if I do that, the line would be....      .Attachments.Add (file path) ?  and will the new data from the active database be updated as new information is added?

Comment: Brian M Stafford this is how i have it, it's still doing the same. i am going to try to export it to a new workbook and link it that way.

Comment: I wrote you an example as answer

Answer (score 1):

Example

```
    Private Sub cmdEmail_Click()
    'Declare Outlook Variables
    Dim OLApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OLMail As Object
    'Open the Outlook Application and Start a new mail
    Set OLApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set OLMail = OLApp.CreateItem(0)
    OLApp.Session.Logon
    With OLMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = ""
        .body = ""
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Database")
        ws.Copy
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
           Dim fullName As String
           fullName = "E:\Temp\Database.xlsx" ' Change Path
        On Error Resume Next ' quick and dirty better in a sub or check if file exists
        Kill fullName
        On Error GoTo 0
        wb.SaveAs fullName
              .Attachments.Add wb.fullName
          wb.Close False
        .Display
        ' .Send
    End With
    
    'Clearing Memory
    
    Set OLMail = Nothing
    Set OLApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: The only problem is when i go to email the report a second time or more it is giving me a prompt saying the file already exist and asking if I want to replace it how do I prevent that from happening

Comment: Check if file exists (search in SO) and then Delete the file e.g. with the kill command: 
`Kill "E:\Temp\Database.xlsx"` 
(Would be nice to flag the answer as solved :-))

Comment: Where would I insert that line? After the ' Send and before the End With

Comment: I keep getting a runtime error. with the  Kill "C:\Temp\Database.xlsx"

Comment: Changed the code to kill the beast :-) and close file - but beware it is only example code